# Assign contact id to user in apex code

Tags: apex, contact, user

I am trying to write the following piece of code

```
Contact aContact=[select FirstName, LastName, UserId__r.id,id,email from contact where id=:ContactId limit 1];
                             if(aContact.UserId__r.id == null){
                                User u = new User();
                                u.FirstName = aContact.FirstName;
                                u.LastName = aContact.LastName;
                                u.Email = aContact.Email;
                                u.Contact = aContact.Id;                               
                                aContact.UserId__r.id = u.id;                               
                            }
```

Here UserId__c is a custom field in Contact which stores the UserId. This code is showing me an error

Illegal assignment from Id to Contact

Please tell me where am I going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in here

```
u.Contact = aContact.Id;
```

You have to change this into

```
u.ContactId = aContact.Id;
```

But I've no idea about below line

```
aContact.UserId__r.id = u.id;
```

as per your code snippet, `u.Id` is not available at this line since the user instance has not been inserted yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned Id to an object, you need to assign it to the Id field. It should be:

```
u.ContactId = aContact.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message I would say that you problem is on this line:

```
u.Contact = aContact.Id;
```

You should use *ContactId* instead of just *Contact* here